# How is URL Routing handled when the URLs are 3+ levels deep? (RESTful URLs)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

So let's say you need to have these URLs in your RESTful routing:

```
/Company/About

/Company/Product/View
/Company/Product/Edit

/Company/Contact/View
/Company/Contact/Edit
```

I assume that all of these actions would need to be in the same controller (i.e. Company) and I also assume that the routing would look something like this in Global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
     routes.MapRoute("mission", "Company/Product/{action}/{id}",
          new { controller = "Company", id = "" });

     routes.MapRoute("mission", "Company/Contract/{action}/{id}",
          new { controller = "Company", id = "" });

     routes.MapRoute(
          "Default",                                              
          "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" } 
     );
}
```

The problem arises when trying to cram all of this into the one controller (and, again, my assumption is that having all of this in the same controller is correct) because the controller action names will mess everything up.  Here is what I mean by this:

In this example, we will need controller actions named the following in the Company controller:

```
About (for Company/About)

ProductView (for /Company/Product/View)
ProductEdit (for /Company/Product/Edit)

ContactView (for /Company/Contact/View)
ContactEdit (for /Company/Contact/Edit)
```

These action names, however, don't match what is going to be expected by the routing table.  For example, if the user browses to /Company/Product/View the routing would direct flow to the action named "View" in the Company controller.  What if the user browses to /Company/Contact/View?  The routing will route flow to the same "View" table in the Company controller.  How would one route these requests to different Views?

How would you solve this issue?  My goal is to be as RESTful as possible.

Comment: `/Company/Contact/Edit` would usually suggest that you're using an `Area` named `Company`

Answer (score 0):

First to be RESTful you shouldn't be including the actions in the route names. Instead of specifiying edit or view in the route you should be routing through http verbs. I would also suggest using attribute routing

Here's an example controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/company")]
public class CompanyController : ApiController
{
    [Route("product"), HttpGet]
    public Product ViewProduct()
    {
    }

    [Route("product"), HttpPut]
    public Product EditProduct()
    {
    }

    [Route("contact"), HttpGet]
    public Product ViewContact()
    {
    }

    [Route("contact"), HttpPut]
    public Product EditContact()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly do you do this in ASP.NET MVC though?  I mean if you've got /{controller}/{action} setup in the route, you always have to put an action name into the URL.  For example, you can't just do /Contract/12483 (which is the RESTful way to do it) to view a contract because the route is expecting an action name where the ID is.  This is the truly RESTful way to do it, but it can't be done in ASP.NET MVC because of the need to include the action name in the URL.

Comment: The method I proposed is using attribute routing. So you can do [Route("contract/{id}")] and then add id to the method parameters. With attribute routing you no longer have to conform to the /{controller}/{action} convention way of doing routing. This link may help http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2